# How to reset a Cisco ATA 186 to factory defaults?

Tags: cisco, voip, telephony, password-reset, reset

I have an old Cisco ATA 186, configured by an extincted Phone Service Company, it is password protected and on TFTP client mode.

I tried to reset it with IVR FACTRESET code (322873738#) but it ask for password before I can press * to confirm.

I called to Cisco Support but they cant help me because I haven´t a contract.

Is there another way to reset it?

Here is what I have found so far:

> Q. How can I recover the ATA 186 if I forget the password?
>
> A. There are two important passwords for ATA 186. One is the
>   UIPassword, which protects access to the ATA web server interface. The
>   other password is the EncryptKey, which protects access to the TFTP
>   profile. If you forgot the value for the UIPassword but still have
>   access to provision with TFTP, you can modify the UIPassword through
>   TFTP. However, if you are not provisioning via TFTP, or you forgot
>   both passwords, open a case with the Cisco TAC to further
>   troubleshoot. Refer to Contact TAC to open a case.

[Cisco ATA 186 FAQ and Common Issues](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/ata-180-series-analog-telephone-adaptors/19302-ata-faq.html)

Answer (score 1):

The ATA must be powered on and disconnected from network.

- Connect an analog phone with full keypad (Unhooked)
- Press the function button on the top of the ATA
- Enter the following: 322873738#*​
- Enter * to save
- Hang Up

Notes:
- you need to also hand up at the end
- * (save) may require a little pause so try a second or 2 of delay between # and * or after the #* wait a little and give it another *

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps to reset:**

- Power up the ATA
- Make sure the ATA is *NOT* plugged into the network.
- Plug an analogue phone into voice port one.
- Lift the handset, and    press the button on top of the ATA
- You will be greeted by the    American female darlek.
- Dial 322873738#*

Comment: I did it, doesnt work